# How do I disable 3D anaglyph display mode in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My game has gone into 3D anaglyph red-cyan mode and I don't know how to return it to its normal screen.

Comment: Answer is the same, question is not. I don't think that makes it a duplicate, does it?

Comment: @TZHX Actually, the question definitely seems to be the same, if worded slightly differently.

Answer (score 11):

- Go to options menu (press the escape key)
- Select "Video Settings"
- There is an option here for "3D Anaglyph", you disable it there.

[image]

Comment: "Analgyph" - funny mistake :)

Comment: @user11153 Thanks for spotting it! :)

Comment: I wonder why that feature was ever implemented.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms with 3D glasses it looks awesome

Comment: @imulsion Hmm, I'll have to try that. I bet skeletons get 10 times more terrifying..